# Creating Domain Relationships in Grails returns unable to resolve class error

Tags: grails, groovy

Good day to all. I am very new in using grails and I have followed several tutorials for beginners using grails until I come up in creating domain relationships. However, I got stuck with this problem right now. I have 3 domain classes namely, todo, category and user. And as I defined their relationships, it returns me an error saying unable to resolve class. Please see my codes below. Please help. Thank you so much.

**Todo.groovy Class**

```
package todoScaff

class Todo {

  String name
  String note
  Date createDate
  Date dueDate
  Date completedDate
  String priority
  String status
  User owner
  Category category

  static belongsTo = [User, Category]

static constraints = {
    name(blank:false)
    createDate()
    priority()
    status()
    note(maxsize:1000, nullable:true)
    completedDate(nullable:true)
    dueDate(nullable:true)
}


 String toString() {
    name
 }


}
```

**Category.groovy Class**

```
package categoryScaff

class Category {

  String name
  String description
  User user
  static belongsTo = User
  static hasMany = [todos: Todo]


  static constraints = {
    name(blank:false)
  }

 String toString(){
    name
 }

}
```

**User.groovy Class**

```
package userScaff

class User {

  String userName
  String fname
  String lname

  static hasMany = [todos: Todo, categories: Category]

  static constraints = {

    userName(blank:false, unique:true)
    fname(blank:false)
    lname(blank:false)
}

  String toString(){
    "$lname, $fname"
  }

}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Were you able to fix the problem?

Comment: Not yet sir. There is another error after I add the import lines. Please take a look above. Thank you so much. Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've placed your domain classes in different packages, you must import the classes at the head of the file.

```
package categoryScaff

import todoScaff.Todo
import userScaff.User

class Category {
```

The same needs to happen in your other domain classes that reference classes outside the current package.

Comment: After I put this lines, the server runs successfully but as I visit the todo, category, and user url it returns the error above.Please see above images with errors. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.  Taking a quick glance at your stack trace seems to indicate the columns make me named incorrectly; did you set the database up yourself or have grails do it?

Comment: I just set up the database with myself using mysql.

Comment: You can either add a `static mapping` closure in your domain classes and give explicit column names matching the names you used in your database, or change the actual names to reflect what  gorm expects.

Comment: Please help me with this.

Comment: It's out of the scope of this question, start a new one and I'll be happy to help, but I can't do much within comments.  Here is a link to the documentation [Grails 2.4 mapping](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/mapping.html); you would need the `column` attribute.